# Schedule for Lightwave RF thermostat

Tags: smart-home, lightwave-rf

I have a LightwaveRF thermostatic radiator valve, and a hub to connect this to the internet. Setting a schedule seems particularly problematic. [This](http://www.lightwaverf.com/product/922-radiator-wave/) is the valve in question.

I have the option of an Android app, or the website, each seems to have their own problems around the 6am point which is designated as the end of day.

If I set a schedule using the web interface, it doesn't seem to be synced across to the mobile view.

Is there any reliable way to edit these schedules? I see there are old comments in various places which confirm these are not unique problems. I'd rather not set up a dedicated server for control, but it's an option.

I want a profile like this:

```
5am-7:30    20°C   
10pm-11pm   20°C
11pm-5am    18°C
```

The design of both UIs appears to insist there are no active settings spanning 6am. It seems very easy to enter parameters which are detected by the web page as conflicting between one day and another. Even setting 5am seems to confuse the system - it gets automatically put in the previous day.

Comment: 6am == end of day. Looks like the developers did not read any user stories here.

Comment: Is this the device in question [LightwaveRF thermostatic radiator valve](http://www.lightwaverf.com/product/922-radiator-wave/)

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the schedule? *Just* regular on/off events? What is the problem with 6am?

Comment: @Helmar A simple bedroom temperature schedule. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is an online scheduling service you could use. [If this then that](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time) offers date time applets that can trigger certain events. They also do have [Lightwave RF heating](https://ifttt.com/applets/415943p-fully-open-a-lightwaverf-trv-when-the-temperature-gets-cold) recipes that prove that IFTTT works with the valve in general.

If you are not opposed to writing an IFTTT recipe you might be able to create a recipe there where you can create the schedule - maybe even a configurable schedule - that triggers your valves. The [API of the valve] seems to indicate that the commands should be available in theory.

This might be a way. I'll try to detail it a bit more later on.

Comment: I can have a play with that. I already use IFTTT, so I can see if its viable.

Comment: Yes, IFTTT has the right hooks to be able to achieve this. Seem like I have to set '@time, temp=target' at each change-point. Crude but effective.